Will bristleworms harm my snails?
Question: Will bristleworms harm my snails?
I got a rock from Petco and alas it has bristleworms and Spionid Worms. One bristleworm is a little bigger than the rest. The tank only has snails and a little piece of coral.
These buddies alright to keep?


